# How to use Concat("String", '', MySQL Query) in Trigger MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

how to use concat("Operation Name", ' just for space ', (MySQL Query select from another table)?

tried like this :

```
INSERT INTO log
set operation = "create",
detail= Concat("Creating new Data", ' ', (SELECT name from employees where employees.id = new.employ_id)),
time = NOW()
```

but i got an error in third argument in detail...

but if i tried like this :

```
INSERT INTO log
set operation = "create",
detail= SELECT name from employees where employees.id = new.employ_id,
time = NOW()
```

employees name can showed if i create a new data in my table

how to fix this one? help pls

thanks

Comment: Your should specify what the error is.  The second `insert` shouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be writing the logic like this:

```
INSERT INTO log(operation, detail, time)
    SELECT 'create',
            concat('Creating new Data', ' ', e.name),
            NOW()
    FROM employees e
    WHERE e.id = new.employ_id;
```

I'm not sure if this fixes your error -- you haven't specified what it is.  This is, however, a more natural way to write the query.

Comment: thanks for your answer ! i think i must doing more practice about this one :)